# script a macro for imacro

Tags: html, imacros

I would like to create a script in `imacro` that goes to a website and click some `html` elements, but with logic in it. For example if a button contains a string or an id so I want to click on it.

I can't seem to find the way to do that. So far I only found examples like this:

```
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://demo.imacros.net/Automate/Extract2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:H*links* EXTRACT=HREF 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:H*links* EXTRACT=TITLE 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:H*links* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Is there a language you can write a script with logic and do things you can't do with the simple recording feature? Is there a tutorial for that, I only found tutorials explaining [how to use the GUI and the recording feature](https://wiki.imacros.net/Tutorials).

Comment: Perhaps you could use the **AutoIT** scripting language, but it is a bit more complicated than the simple iMacros plug-in in your web browser. AutoIT uses DOM objects for Internet Explorer, and you can even open Internet Explorer's hidden windows. Of course, in AutoIT you can do a lot more than just manipulate a web page through Internet Explorer. It's a scripting language that can do a lot of things.

Comment: @ben Imacros can do much more than you think, it just needs a middleman called `javascript` for doing if condition, please do checkout the [imacros and javascript](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/5t702r/conditional_statements_with_iimgetlastextract/), scour the internet to learn more!